# Capturing warnings isn't working within user-defined function but works outside of it

Tags: r, warnings, user-defined-functions

so, I am trying to automate the creation of tables for some simply analyses.  There are lots and lots of tables, thus the creation of a user-defined function to make and output them to excel.

My problem is that some of the analyses have convergence issues, which I want captured and included in the output so the folks looking at them know how to view those estimates.

I am successfully able to do this in a straightforward set of steps.  However, once I place those steps inside a function it fails.

Here's the code:

```
# create data
wt <- rgamma(6065, 0.7057511981,  0.0005502062)
grp <- sample(c(replicate(315, "Group1"), replicate(3672, "Group2"), replicate(1080, "Group3"), replicate(998, "Group4")))
dta <- data.frame(grp, wt)
head(dta)
str(dta)

# declare design
my.svy <- svydesign(ids=~1, weights=~wt, data=dta)

# subset
grp1 <- subset(my.svy, grp == "Group1")

# set options and clear old warnings
options(warn=0)
assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())

## proportions and CIs
p <- ((svyciprop(~grp, grp1, family=quasibinomial))[1])

# save warnings
wrn1 <- warnings(p)

ci_l <- (confint(svyciprop(~grp, grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[1])
ci_u <- (confint(svyciprop(~grp, grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[2])

## sample counts
n <- unwtd.count(~grp, grp1)[1]

## combine into table
overall <- data.frame(n, p, ci_l, ci_u)
colnames(overall) <- c("counts", "Group1", "LL", "UL")

## add any warnings
ind <- length(wrn1)
ind

if (ind == 0) { msg <- "No warnings" }
if (ind > 0) {msg <- names(warnings()) }
overall[1,5] <- msg

print(overall)
```

Here's the output from the above:

```
> # set options and clear old warnings
> options(warn=0)
> assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())
> 
> ## proportions and CIs
> p <- ((svyciprop(~grp, grp1, family=quasibinomial))[1])
Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
> 
> # save warnings
> wrn1 <- warnings(p)
> 
> ci_l <- (confint(svyciprop(~grp, grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[1])
Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
> ci_u <- (confint(svyciprop(~grp, grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[2])
Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
> 
> ## sample counts
> n <- unwtd.count(~grp, grp1)[1]
> 
> ## combine into table
> overall <- data.frame(n, p, ci_l, ci_u)
> colnames(overall) <- c("counts", "Group1", "LL", "UL")
> 
> ## add any warnings
> ind <- length(wrn1)
> ind
[1] 1
> 
> if (ind == 0) { msg <- "No warnings" }
> if (ind > 0) {msg <- names(warnings()) }
> overall[1,5] <- msg
> 
> print(overall)
       counts       Group1           LL           UL                                  V5
counts    315 2.364636e-12 2.002372e-12 2.792441e-12 glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

Here's the function:

```
est <- function(var) {

## set up formula
formula <- paste ("~", var)

## set options and clear old warning
options(warn=0)
assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())

## proportions and CIs
p <- ((svyciprop(as.formula(formula), grp1, family=quasibinomial))[1])

## save warnings
wrn1 <- warnings(p)

ci_l <- (confint(svyciprop(as.formula(formula) , grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[1])
ci_u <- (confint(svyciprop(as.formula(formula) , grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[2])

## sample counts
n <- unwtd.count(as.formula(formula), grp1)[1]

## combine into table
overall <- data.frame(n, p, ci_l, ci_u)
colnames(overall) <- c("counts", "Group1", "LL", "UL")


## add any warnings
ind <- length(warnings(p))
print(ind)

if (ind == 0) { msg <- "No warnings" }
if (ind > 0) {msg <- names(warnings()) }
overall[1,5] <- msg

print(overall)

}

# call function
est("grp")
```

Here's the output from running the function:

```
> est("grp")
[1] 0
       counts       Group1           LL           UL          V5
counts    315 2.364636e-12 2.002372e-12 2.792441e-12 No warnings
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
3: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

So, the warnings are showing up in the output at the end of the function but they're not being captured like they are when run outside of the function.  Note the 0 output from print(ind) and V7 has "No warnings".

I know a lot of things "behave" differently inside functions.  Case in point, the use of "as.formula(var)" rather than just "~grp" being passed to the function.

I've failed to find a solution after much searching of various R related forums.  So, if anyone can help, I'd be appreciative.

(sidenote: I used rgamma to create my sampling weights because that's what most resembles the distribution of my weights and it's close enough to reproduce the convergence issue.  If I used rnorm or even rlnorm or rweibull I couldn't reproduce it. Just FYI.)

Comment: I cannot seem to find your function `est` above

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did forget to include it.  BRB - ok, it's there now.  Spent so much time focusing on format I forgot content.  Story of my life, sometimes.

Comment: Hi @RolandASc does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so thanks to William Dunlap via r-help I got this solved.  It involves using withCallingHandlers:

```
withWarnings <- function(expr) {
   .warnings <- NULL # warning handler will append to this using '<<-'
   value <- withCallingHandlers(expr,
                                warning=function(e) {
                                    .warnings <<- c(.warnings, conditionMessage(e))
                                    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
                                })
   structure(value, warnings=.warnings)
}
```

And then I have to modify my original function "est" so the captured warning is stored as an object right as it occurs, before it's overwritten:

```
## save warnings
ind <- length(attr(p, "warnings"))
if (ind == 0) { 
msg <- "No warnings"
} else {
msg <- attr(p, "warnings")
}
```

Right after calling on svyciprop.

Here's the whole function, including building the dataset (so anyone can just copy this and run it to see how it works):

```
library(survey)

# create data
wt <- rgamma(6065, 0.7057511981,  0.0005502062)
grp <- sample(c(replicate(315, "Group1"), replicate(3672, "Group2"), replicate(1080, "Group3"), replicate(998, "Group4")))
dta <- data.frame(grp, wt)
head(dta)
str(dta)

# declare design
my.svy <- svydesign(ids=~1, weights=~wt, data=dta)

# subset
grp1 <- subset(my.svy, grp == "Group1")

# set up function to capture warnings
withWarnings <- function(expr) {
   .warnings <- NULL # warning handler will append to this using '<<-'
   value <- withCallingHandlers(expr,
                                warning=function(e) {
                                    .warnings <<- c(.warnings, conditionMessage(e))
                                    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
                                })
   structure(value, warnings=.warnings)
}

# build user-defined function
est <- function(var) {

## set up formula
formula <- paste ("~", var)

## set options and clear old warning
assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())
msg<-NULL

## proportions and CIs
p <- withWarnings((svyciprop(as.formula(formula), grp1, family=quasibinomial))[1])

## save warnings
ind <- length(attr(p, "warnings"))
if (ind == 0) { 
msg <- "No warnings"
} else {
msg <- attr(p, "warnings")
}

ci_l <- (confint(svyciprop(as.formula(formula) , grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[1])
ci_u <- (confint(svyciprop(as.formula(formula) , grp1, family=quasibinomial), 'ci')[2])

## sample counts
n <- unwtd.count(as.formula(formula), grp1)[1]

## combine into table
overall <- data.frame(n, p, ci_l, ci_u)
colnames(overall) <- c("counts", "Group1", "LL", "UL")


## add any warnings
overall[1,5] <- msg

print(overall)

}

# call function
est("grp")
```

And here's the output:

```
> # call function
> est("grp")
       counts       Group1           LL           UL                                  V5
counts    315 2.417004e-12 2.040761e-12 2.862612e-12 glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
>
```

This was very useful and I am grateful to William Dunlap for his hep.  I hope this helps someone else